# Absolutely centering a large table

Tags: html, html-table, center

I have a table which uses a background image that is 1500px wide. Since this is wider than many screens can view without scrollbars, I'm trying to figure out how to center this table within the page body so that the zoom focus is always on the absolute center of the table image, allowing the far left and right sides of the image to run offscreen on a close zoom.

I found that giving the page body an overflow-x:hidden property allows the sides to run offscreen without creating a scrollbar, but I can't seem to keep the thing centered on zoom.

I contemplated creating another table to contain this table with left and right tds that can expand as needed, but this hasn't proven fruitful just yet.

Here is my test case:

css:

```
    #login_table {
        position:absolute;
        width:1500px;
        margin:auto;
        border:none;
    }
    .login_table_bookend {
        width:238px;
        height:896px;
    }
    #login_center_wrap {
        width:1024px;
        height:896px;
        background:url('center.jpg') no-repeat;
    }
```

html:

```
        <table id="login_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td class="login_table_bookend" style="background:url('left.jpg') no-repeat;">
            </td>
            <td id="login_center_wrap">

            </td>
            <td class="login_table_bookend" style="background:url('right.jpg') no-repeat;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why are you using width: 1500px; when you can do max-width: 1500px;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following:

```
#login_table {
    ...
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -750px;  /* half of the width of the table */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vertically and horizontally align it using just CSS providing you know the width and height.

http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

If you don't know the width and the height (because it varies) you could always use javascript or jquery to get it.